# Laravel Excel ( Export ) not working - Page not found

Tags: export-to-excel

> `this is my controller`

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Exports\DatabaseExport;
use App\Imports\DatabaseImport;
use App\Models\Database;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class ExcelController extends Controller
{
    public function exportexcel() 
    {
        return Excel::download(new DatabaseExport, 'database-'.Carbon::now()->timestamp.'.xlsx');
    }
```

> `this is my Router`

```
Route::get('/exportexcel' , [ExcelController::class, 'exportexcel'])->name('exportexcel');
```

> `and this is for the blade`

```
  <div class="col-auto mt-2t">
         <a href="/exportexcel" class="btn btn-danger">EXPORT EXCEL</a> 
      </div>
```

I have tried to create a new controller specifically for excel.

then I also tried to rename the router and call it in the controller, but the page still can't be found.

update `this is the route:list`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KXu0Q.png)

Comment: I have reproduced this on my machine and seems to work well. How about you try `php artisan cache:clear` if that fails, try `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: @Benson Okello still error

Comment: run this `php artisan optimize:clear` I thought it was the first option I written in my previous response. You may need to run php artisan route:list and share a screenshot of its output

Comment: I've tried, but nothing happens and it keeps crashing.

Comment: Can you share the output of `php artisan route:list` ? Are you running `php artisan serve` or serving the files from a webserver like Apache?

Comment: of course,I've tried

Comment: Share an out of each of those commands and if it results in error, take a screenshot of the output. I can't do much while  speculating

Comment: there was no error when I ran those commands, but the error is still the same

Comment: Can you share the output of `php artisan route:list` ?

Comment: I've added the image